# How to see if the function or procedure is private, protected or public without scrolling to the top

Tags: delphi, ide, access-modifiers

Is it possible to know if the function or procedure is private, protected or public.
Now I must scroll to the top to see if the methode is private.
Is there a tool or in the structure (Code Explorer) to see if the methode is private, protected or public whitout scrolling to the top.

example:

```
 unit .....
 // 100 line code
 private
 // 1000 line code
   procedure A(); // <-- Here I can't see if the procedure is private. Must scroll to the top
 //  2000 line code 
 ...
 procedure A();  // <-- Here I can't see if the procedure is private. Must scroll to the top
 begin
   ...
 end;
```

The only thing I can to now is to set (private, protected or public) it the the summary description

In Code Explorer I see blue color for procedure and green color for function but nothing for private, protected or public icon.

I changed the properties of the Explore Code and now I have maps of private , protected or pulic.

But when I go to a procedure in the code there is no selected item in the explore code like in the Project Manager view.
The same situation for the Explore Code. Must scroll up to the map to see if it is private, protected or public
One alternatieve is the write the methode in the search of the explored code. Then ther is a hint popup.

I found the possible solution: Copy the methode and past to the searchbox of the explorer code. The comboboxlist popup give me what I want to see (private, protected...)

Comment: Doesn't the code explorer window do what you need http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Code_Explorer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  I can't see in the Code Explore structure if the methode is private, protected or public.

Comment: Doesn't it have icons to indicate that? I can't check now. Or what about Structure View?

Comment: No, only blue (procedure) or green color (function)

Comment: @Ravaut123, you have to check those items in the tools|options|Environment options|explorer dialog.

Comment: Ok, thanks finded in the structure. Changed the propertie of the Code Explore

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Structure View](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Structure_View#Nodes_and_Items_for_the_Code_Explorer_.28Delphi.29) to show all details about class declarations.

To control the appearance of the view, define the settings in `Tools > Options > Environment Options > Explorer` dialog.

---

**Update**

As noted in comments, you have to manually navigate the structure view to view the class structure.

Filed enhancement request [QC 128271 Structure view lookup from editor](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=128271) to facilitate a quick lookup into the structure view from the editor.

Comment: Is there also something that it select the item automatically in the explore code like the project manager viewer.

Comment: Double clicking in the structure view, directs the editor to corresponding item. Double clicking in the source editor does not have the effect of high-lighting the item in the structure view. Perhaps a good thing to report as a request in QC.

Comment: the approximate solution: copy the methode and past into the searchbox of the exlpore code. The popuphint give the info.

Comment: +1 That's probably what the structure view is there for. Though overloaded methods are grouped together under the highest visibility specifier.

Answer (score 3):

> ... without scrolling to the top

Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>UP</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>DOWN</kbd>) to jump to the declaration.

And use the same to jump back to the implementation again.

If it is not clear to which section (private, protected or public) the declaration belongs right away, then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>UP</kbd> to scroll without moving the cursor.

Comment: If you have a small class this will work. Try to go into the VCL code and try your tick.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt:  Those shortcuts work fine for me in the source code D7 & XE4, including ComCtrls.Pas and MSHTML.Pas, which are the largest source files I could find.

Comment: What @Jens means is that there are so many declarations in large classes, you have to scroll to find the visibility specifier.

Comment: @Jens I see what you mean, but I think that that specific (tiny) extra bit of scrolling compensates sufficiently, in both time and effort, for: using mouse, or scrolling to a location you don't know where to search for, folding, searching and unfolding the items in the structure view, or searching with CTRL-F.

Comment: This can also be done by right-click and select `Find Declaration` on top of the popup menu.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [ModelMaker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html). It's not free, but well worth the money. It shows a lot of information and provides some really useful refactorings.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. because Delphi splits its classes into two pices interface and implementation.

In fx. c# you do it diffrent

```
public static byte[] ColumnBlob(Sqlite3Statement stmt, int index)
{
    return Sqlite3.sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, index);
}
```

While in Delphi you'll spilt the class into thw :

```
type 
   TSQLiteException  = class(TException)
   public
     class function  ColumnBlob(stmt : Sqlite3Statement, index : integer) : TArray<byte>;
   end;
```

and the impelmentation:

```
function TSQLiteException.ColumnBlob(stmt : Sqlite3Statement, index : integer) : TArray<byte> ;
begin
  //Do stuff
end;
```

There are ups and downs in boths methods:

the c# way you can see the protection level of the class while you can not see wich class you are with in

And the othere way arround with Delphi